# system-wide TCP parameter in linux to kill broken connexion between user applications

Tags: linux, tcp

I wrote a tcp server/clients application (Linux, C) and if clients shutdown without sending FIN/ACK I have issues to reuse immediately same port (restart application). Is it possible to tune the system-wide TCP parameter settings as tcp_keepalive_intvl, tcp_keepalive_probes, tcp_keepalive_time to kill broken tcp connection and free the ports for reuse?

Answer (score 0):

> if clients shutdown without sending FIN/ACK I have issues to reuse immediately same port (restart application).

So use `SO_REUSEADDR`. That's what it's for.

> Is it possible to tune the system-wide TCP parameter settings as tcp_keepalive_intvl, tcp_keepalive_probes, tcp_keepalive_time to kill broken tcp connection and free the ports for reuse?

You're barking up the wrong tree here.